# A few simple riddles to get your brain going

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, liars, situation

Here are a couple of riddles for you.

1.) Where does twelve plus two equal two?

2.) A man walks up to you and says "If you tell a lie I will stab you with a knife. If you tell the truth I will shoot you with a gun." What do you say to get out of this?

3.) My house is incredibly strong but breaks with a single tap what am I?

Comment: There are too many answers being made for this question.....I think it should be closed

Comment: I would agree with MarkN. If you can find some simple additional requirements to edit this with, then you can work to reopen it.

Comment: I think that the answers already satisfy the first two questions for the most part and the third riddle is possibly beer?  The keg is very strong, but the seal breaks as soon as it is tapped.  The keg is the home for the beer.

Answer (score 10):

3.

> The House of Representatives. I believe the speaker of the house breaks the session with the tap of a gavel.

Comment: I *like* this answer, especially your explanation of the "single tap" part.

Comment: That would imply the it's strong in the first place...

Answer (score 9):

1.

> A clock

2.

> "You're going to stab me with the knife"

3.

> A wooden ship (or houseboat). If the tap is the kind of tap one would use to collect sap from a tree, inserting it in the bottom of the boat would cause it to fill with water and sink (probably not the "right" answer, but still).

Comment: For 3 I would not consider a house of cards strong... I'm thinking it's an egg.

Comment: Good point. I'm definitely not awake yet then, as I missed the incredibly strong part. Though I'm not sure it would be an egg either.

Comment: It is definitely part of an egg although its not letting me mouse over the last one to see what you put...

Comment: @WilliamKnapp Why not an Odd Aquarium tank with a "Single TAP"

Comment: @WilliamKnapp What if #3 is a houseboat?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a ship is a sailor's home (since a ship is generally stronger than a houseboat), but a houseboat does provide a clearer answer.

Comment: I don't think I would consider a sunken ship to be broken as such.. Egg sounds about right.

Comment: The *house* breaks with a single tap, but the question was "What am *I*".

Comment: Based on MediaMagnet's comment on this, I'm guessing the "correct" answer to part 3 is the chick/embryo in the egg. Though I definitely wouldn't classify an eggshell as "incredibly strong."

Comment: Your answer for number 2 will not work.  He can just do both.  It probably is intended, however.

Comment: He can't just do both and still follow his own logic (though if he is threatening your life he probably doesn't have the morality to stick to his own promises). If you say he'll stab you and he does, then you'll have told a truth and he'll shoot you. But you won't have told a lie, so by his logic he can't stab you.

Comment: @WillianKnapp  he does not say "I will stab you and only stab you if you lie.  I will shoot you and only shoot you if you tell the truth."  Ergo "both" fits his statements perfectly.

Comment: @kaine How about "You will **only** stab me with the knife"

Comment: @VictorHenry Does you will stab me with a knife and not shoot me work? No. That is essentially the same.

Answer (score 3):

Part 2: There's plenty of answers for this one, besides what WilliamKnapp said.

1. > I am telling a lie.
2. > Today is opposite day.
3. > Bwfffhlkbnm! (Since he doesn't understand this one, he can't tell if you are lying.)

Part 3:

> The unhatched chick in an egg.
>  The house is a eggshell, which has a structure that makes it (sort of) hard to break from the outside. It breaks easily from a tap from the chick's beak from the inside.

Answer (score 2):

For question 2: Say nothing and run away.  As valid an answer as any other, much more realistic, and violent crazy people are not (in my experience) fond of smart-asses.

Comment: He's got a *gun*, for god's sake. He could just shoot you in the back while you're running.

Comment: As a wise man once said: any man who is likely to shoot you in the back as you run away is as likely to shoot you in the face as you stand there.  If you are running away, at least you're harder to hit.  This isn't a TV show or a movie; don't kid yourself into thinking that negotiating with the crazy person with a gun is the safest plan.

Answer (score 1):

1

> An analogue clock. Those newfangled digital clocks won't do for this.

2

> Logically one could say "You will stab me with a knife." If you're telling the truth, he's going to stab you with a knife, but he only does that if you tell a lie. Of course, I also would consider hypnosis and then run away while he's asleep.

3

> They say spider silk is the strongest natural substance. I don't know who they are, though. Like Mia Wallace wisely said, "They talk a lot, don't they?" to which Vincent Vega replied "They certainly do." But anyway apparently per unit cross-sectional area, spider silk is supposed to be really strong. But it's also really thin so a single tap from a human will demolish it. So I'll say you're a spider.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to #2 is to say

> Nothing. A truth or a lie will get you shot or stabbed, but saying nothing at all falls under neither of these categories and would thus leave you alive.

Comment: I like that as an alternate answer.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add an explanation as to why this answer is correct? Answers without explanations may be deleted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Question 2:

You could also ask him a question. "WHY? OH PLEASE NO, WHY?" is pathetic but not untrue or true.  This won't get you out of it though unless you can keep it up forever...

Question 3:

Your house could be factory, restaurant, or other business.  It will not last very long with only one tap (sink).

Comment: "Oh please no" could be interpreted as a statement :-p

Comment: @randal'thor Yes but an expletive.  I intentionally included it to show the expletives are also not true or false.  "Ouch" works.  "Ouch that hurt" doesn't.  Knowing the first should help you not get shot after you have already been stabbed.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Where does twelve plus two equal two?

> In a [Matchstick Puzzle](http://www.learning-tree.org.uk/stickpuzzles/stick_puzzles.htm). We start off with 12... and then add two matches to make it 1 X 2, which is two! [image]

2.) A man walks up to you and says "If you tell a lie I will stab you with a knife. If you tell the truth I will shoot you with a gun." What do you say to get out of this?

> "What if I ask you a question instead?"